# Updated: Featured Image behind post title on WordPress Homepage (columns)

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I have a WordPress site with multiple posts. On the homepage I have setup a plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/column-posts/) so that three columns of the most recent posts are displayed. That works well and I'm able to style the columns in CSS. However, I want each post's featured image to be the background of that post's column? Any idea how I'd make this happen?

```
<ul>
            ';
        }

        // thumbnail
        $thclear = '';
        $bullet = '<li style="background:url(<?php'.$thumb.'?>);">';
        $thumb = '';
        if ( $args['thumb'] ) {
            if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) {
                //$bullet = '';
                $thclear = '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
                $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), $args['tsize'], false, array('class'=>"alignthumb"));
            }
        }
        $ppost .= $bullet .'<a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'" title="'.sprintf(__('Article %s published at %s', 'cp'), $title_full, date_i18n(__('F j, Y g:i a'), strtotime($post->post_date)) ).'">'.$title.'</a>';

        // excerpt
        if ( $args['excerpt'] ) {
            $ppost .= '<p>' .get_the_excerpt() .'</p>' .$thclear .'</li>';
        }
        else{
            $ppost .= $thclear .'</li>';
        }

        if ($args['class'] == 'P' && $args['col_cnt'] == $args['col_post'])
            $ppost .= '
            </ul>
```

I figured I could plug a variable into li style like this:

```
<li style="background:url(<?php'.$thumb.'?>);">
```

However it's not echoing anything at all and no image src for sure. Any way to get it to echo $thumb as the background image or plug a background image somewhere in that code. Thanks!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$image=wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>

<img class="whatever" src="<?php echo $image;?>" />
```

css

```
.whatever {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: WordPress isn't converting <img class="cp-bg" src="<?php echo $image;?>" /> into a src url? Am I coding the echo request correctly? It doesn't appear to be processing that so it just shows up in the html as <img class="whatever" src="<?php echo $image;?>" />

Comment: I updated my question with a bit more information. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you using $thumb before you have defined it. define it with your if statement before the li. remove the <?php tags, so '.$thumb.'